# Excel graphs: How do I apply a graph template format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts, templates

I've created a format that I like. I now need to apply this format to over 900 graphs! I've seen we can save a format as a template for future use, however, I can't find the place where I have the option of applying such a template.

What is the process for applying a user made template in Excel 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy and paste chart formats.  In 2003 and previous versions you copy the graph and then use `Edit>Paste Special` to paste only the formats.  I've no idea of the equivalent ribbon control in 2007/2010 I'm afraid, but I'm reasonably sure it should be there (MS did remove some charting functionality in 2007).

However, with 900 charts even this may a bit of a pain.  You could use a bit of VBA to achieve the same though.

**Edit**: Had a bit of a play about and this will copy the format of Chart1 to all other charts in the worksheet:

```
Sub ReplicateChartFormats()
    Dim c As ChartObject

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        With c.Chart
            .Paste Type:=xlFormats
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

Again, be aware that this has only been tested in Excel 2003 and the object model in 2007 is missing a few things compared to earlier versions, but this is pretty fundamental stuff so should work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at the paste special (silly of me not to look at that first actually). As for VBA - I'm a novice VBA'er so I wouldn't be able to attempt that type of coding just yet.

Comment: I'm no Jon Peltier and my VBA chart-twiddling-fu is weak so I'll have to pass on a VBA example myself.  Sorry :(

Comment: Seems I have levelled-up somewhat as I managed to get something cobbled together :)

Comment: Copy and paste worked a charm. I'll give the VBA code above a go as it will save me even more time. Thanks again for your time and advice.

Comment: See also: http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/apply-chart-formatting-to-other-charts/